# How to remove space between WPF Toolkit chart area and plot area?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, charts

I am using chartingToolKit:Chart control. I want to remove the white space appear in between the chart and plot area. Attached the WPF sample and image of area to be removed.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" xmlns:chartingToolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit">


<Grid>
    <chartingToolkit:Chart x:Name="chart" Width="500" Height="300" Margin="0, 0, 0, 0"   LegendStyle="{StaticResource LegendStyle}"   >


        <chartingToolkit:AreaSeries ItemsSource="{Binding}"  

                                   DependentValuePath="Value"

                                   IndependentValuePath="Key"

                                   Background="Red"

                                    >


        </chartingToolkit:AreaSeries>

        <chartingToolkit:Chart.Axes>
            <chartingToolkit:LinearAxis Orientation="X" ShowGridLines="False" Visibility="Hidden">

            </chartingToolkit:LinearAxis>
            <chartingToolkit:LinearAxis Orientation="Y" ShowGridLines="False" Visibility="Hidden"/>
        </chartingToolkit:Chart.Axes>

    </chartingToolkit:Chart>
</Grid>
```

**The area marked in red arrow must be removed**
[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In order to achieve this you need to re-template the chart. The standard chart template is as follows:

```
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="charting:Chart">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <datavis:Title Content="{TemplateBinding Title}" Style="{TemplateBinding TitleStyle}" />

                        <!-- Use a nested Grid to avoid possible clipping behavior resulting from ColumnSpan+Width=Auto -->
                        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,15,0,15">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <datavis:Legend x:Name="Legend" Title="{TemplateBinding LegendTitle}" Style="{TemplateBinding LegendStyle}" Grid.Column="1" />
                            <chartingprimitives:EdgePanel x:Name="ChartArea" Style="{TemplateBinding ChartAreaStyle}">
                                <Grid Canvas.ZIndex="-1" Style="{TemplateBinding PlotAreaStyle}" />
                                <Border Canvas.ZIndex="10" BorderBrush="#FF919191" BorderThickness="1" />
                            </chartingprimitives:EdgePanel>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
```

This details the location of the plot area, title, legend etc... It also included a hard-coded margin around the plot area, so you cannot achieve what you are after by simply styling the chart. If you just want a chart area and nothing else, you can simplify the chart template as follows:

```
xmlns:chartingprimitives="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting.Primitives;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"

<Grid>
  <chartingToolkit:Chart x:Name="chart" Width="500" Height="300"
                         Margin="0, 0, 0, 0" Padding="0">
    <chartingToolkit:AreaSeries ItemsSource="{Binding}"  
                                  DependentValuePath="Value"
                                  IndependentValuePath="Key"
                                  Background="Red">
    </chartingToolkit:AreaSeries>
    <chartingToolkit:Chart.Axes>
      <chartingToolkit:LinearAxis Orientation="X" ShowGridLines="False" Height="0">
      </chartingToolkit:LinearAxis>
      <chartingToolkit:LinearAxis Orientation="Y" ShowGridLines="False" Width="0"/>
    </chartingToolkit:Chart.Axes>
    <chartingToolkit:Chart.Template>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="chartingToolkit:Chart">
        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
          <Grid>
            <chartingprimitives:EdgePanel x:Name="ChartArea" Style="{TemplateBinding ChartAreaStyle}">
              <Grid Canvas.ZIndex="-1" Style="{TemplateBinding PlotAreaStyle}" />
              <Border Canvas.ZIndex="10" BorderBrush="#FF919191" BorderThickness="1" />
            </chartingprimitives:EdgePanel>
          </Grid>
        </Border>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </chartingToolkit:Chart.Template>
  </chartingToolkit:Chart>
</Grid>
```

This will remove the padding that you are seeing.

Comment: Thanks for the example. When I add <chartingToolkit:Chart.Template> content, it works but graph is not appearing. Any idea to make it to work?

Comment: Ooops ... looks like I was too aggressive in cutting out parts of the template. I have edited my response above. Note the chart now has Zero padding, and the axes have zero widths / heights.

Comment: How do you remove the white background too? the one behind the area chat. All I need is the steelBlue colored area

Answer (score -1):

To give you a little more space without re-templating the control, set the Margin (as you did) *and* Padding of the chart control to zero.

```
Margin="0" Padding="0"
```